# Reverse Index through a numPy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a n x n dimensional numpy array of eigenvectors as columns, and want to return the last v of them as another array. However, they are currently in ascending order, and I wish to return them in descending order.
Currently, I'm attempting to index as follows

```
eigenvector_array[:,-1:-v]
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What does "this doesn't seem to be working” mean? I suggest reading the numpy indexing tutorial.

Comment: Please add a small example to clarify what you mean and make it clearer to future visitors

Answer (score 2):

Given a 2d array:

```
In [44]: x = np.arange(15).reshape(3,5);x
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

the last 3 columns:

```
In [45]: x[:,-3:]
Out[45]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

and reversing their order:

```
In [46]: x[:,-3:][:,::-1]
Out[46]: 
array([[ 4,  3,  2],
       [ 9,  8,  7],
       [14, 13, 12]])
```

Or we could reverse the order, and take the first n. `x[:,::-1][:,:3]`

I tried combining the selection and order, but getting the end points is trickier.  Separating the operations is easier.

```
x[:,:-4:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets re-write this to make it a little less confusing.

`eigenvector_array[:,-1:-v]`

to:

`eigenvector_array[:][-1:-v]`

Now remember how slicing works in python:

`[start:stop:step]`

If you set `step`. to `-1` it will return them in reverse, so:

`eigenvector_array[:,-1:-v:-1]` should be your answer.